# How to run code in parallel?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

How can i run these two independent loops simultaneously in parallel.

```
let a1=Seq.map2 (fun a b->(1.0-a)/(a-b)) a2  a3

let b1=Seq.map2 (fun a b->a*b) b2 b3
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use standard .NET tasks for this - there are no special F# functions or special syntax for spawning a computation in the background:

```
let a1Work = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () ->
  Array.map2 (fun a b->(1.0-a)/(a-b)) a2  a3)
let b1 = Array.map2 (fun a b->a*b) b2 b3
let a1 = a1Work.Value
```

I also changed your `Seq.map2` to `Array.map2` - computations on sequences are lazy and so running them inside a task would not actually do anything. With arrays, the whole calculation is completed immediately.

Comment: is it `a1 = a1Work.Value` or `a1 = a1Work.Result`

Comment: if there is another loop `let c1=Seq.map2 (fun a b->a/b) c2 c3` do i need to set it as task as well?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a pattern you find yourself using regularly, it could be useful to write a generic function that runs two `Async` computations in parallel, for example like this:

```
module Async =

    let Parallel2 (a: Async<'T>) (b: Async<'U>) : Async<'T * 'U> =
        async {
            let! res =
                Async.Parallel [|
                    async { let! a = a in return box a }
                    async { let! b = b in return box b }
                |]
            return (res.[0] :?> 'T, res.[1] :?> 'U)
        }
```

You can then use it like so:

```
async {
    let! a1, b1 =
        Async.Parallel2
            (async { return Array.map2 (fun a b->(1.0-a)/(a-b)) a2 a3 })
            (async { return Array.map2 (fun a b->a*b) b2 b3 })
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `Array.zip` and `Array.Parallel.map`?

`Array.zip [|1;2;3|] [|2;3;4|] |> Array.Parallel.map (fun (a,b) -> a + b)`

or simply use the `ParallelSeq`(see http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/ for more information)